# Remove duplicate yyyy/mm from array

Tags: php, arrays

How I can remove duplicate entries based on Year and Month when my date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`? I tried removing days, but then I need to add the last day in the array, so my approach was wrong.

My array looks like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9240399
                [time] => 2018-01-01
                [pages_indexed] => 942             
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9240322
                [time] => 2018-01-02
                [pages_indexed] => 940
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9240344
                [time] => 2018-01-03
                [pages_indexed] => 947
            )
        [30] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9240344
                    [time] => 2018-01-31
                    [pages_indexed] => 947
                )
        [31] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9240344
                    [time] => 2018-02-01
                    [pages_indexed] => 1999
                )
        [32] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9240344
                    [time] => 2018-02-02
                    [pages_indexed] => 13339
                )
```

Notice that I skipped some entries, so my dates are `2018-01-01`, `2018-01-02`, etc.
`Array_unique` would not work here since the day is different.

I tried this: ( `$entries['time']` is like ex: `2018-01-01`. )

```
$remove = DATE("Y-m",$entries['time']);
$entriesa = array_unique($remove);
$entries['time'] = $entriesa;
```

Comment: Well `array_unique()` works on an array and you are passing a date

Comment: Yes the date i pass is YYYY-MM-DD but i want to retrive unique based on YYYY-MM because days are unique anyways in a month

Comment: You need to show your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you could loop through your results and index each key as the Year and Month, and then update this index with the row that fits the pattern, meaning you would only have the rows you expect (but you would only have the last reference of them).

Like this:

```
$expectedArray = [];

foreach ($arrayDuplicated as $item) {
    $indexKey = substr($item['time'], 0, 7);

    $expectedArray[$indexKey] = $item;
}
```

Comment: Just realized I accidentally duplicated your answer. Looks like a good idea to me!

Comment: Thank you for deleting it then. :)

Comment: Of course! Sorry, I hadn't really read yours when I posted mine or I wouldn't have bothered. It wasn't me who downvoted yours, though. I upvoted it, in fact.

Comment: Thank you @Rafael. Works perfect. Learned something new today.

Comment: **Don'tPanic**, don't panic(!) mate. No harm done. There are several trolls in SO this days downvoting anything. **Asim**, when in doubt in things like this, always consider arrays, they are underrated for the amount of things they can solve. :)